# Bootstrap navbar doesnt respect text color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML as my navbar:

```
<div id='container_1'>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                  <li><a class="navbar-brand" id='navbar_1' href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a class="navbar-brand" id='navbar_2' href="#">Works</a></li>
                  <li><a class="navbar-brand" id='navbar_3' href="#">Blog</a></li>
                  <li><a class="navbar-brand" id='navbar_4' href="#">Resume</a></li>
                  <li><a class="navbar-brand" id='navbar_5' href="#">Contact</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="appily_header"><h3>Appily</h3></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-push-2" id='iphone_image'>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I cant get the text in the navbar to respect my CSS styling.

But I dont understand why...

```
.navbar-brand{
     color: white;
}
```

...wont style the text, but

```
#navbar_1{
    color: white;
}
```

does work?

**EDIT**

i had to add `!important`....unfortunately.

Comment: Check here working. http://jsfiddle.net/2bagqtsv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colors have not been changed because of the [specificity weight](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/getting-to-know-css/#specificity). If you inspect the navigation bar elements, you will find that bootstrap uses the following css selector to style the color:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
    color:#777;
}
```

while you are trying to change the color using a class:

```
.navbar-brand{
 color: red;
 }
```

It is clear that the former (default Bootstrap selector) is higher than your selector.
You can use important keyword to override the default behavior or use the same same css selector as Bootstrap (if you don't want to use imporat keyword):

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
    color: red;
 }
```

Finally, you can use this useful website to help you calculating the [specificity weight](http://specificity.keegan.st/).

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong element.

use this:

```
.navbar-brand {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: I messed up the original post, I did try that and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

As kevin above, plus:

1. You are using an underscore (_) instead of hyphen (-) when referencing the "navbar-brand" class;
2. Your #navbar_1 ID should style the home link text colour (only), but if that isn't working perhaps try adding an important declaration to force override and see if that works:

   navbar_1{color: white!Important;}
3. Not really related, but I am guessing you know your container reference is odd. Normally you add/change styling by adding a separate class or an ID.
4. Finally, if you are doing wholesale changes to your links, you can style them all with "navbar-defaul" (I think that is the one).

Best luck!! :)

EDIT: Just noting you have changed the underscopre to a hyphen for navbar-brand, so ignore 1.